# Универсальный мессенджер

Tags: windows, messenger

Может, не совсем по теме сайта, но вроде бы в администрирование вписываюсь :)

По работе и не только приходится общаться с кучей разного народа. Посмотрел сегодня на экран и чуть не заплакал. Skype, Viber, Telegram, QIP (в котором включены QIP, VK, OK, ICQ...) Еще и Facebook отдельно в браузере. И везде есть свои контакты, которые на что-то другое переходить не хотят из принципа :(

Можно ли заменить все это стадо мессенджеров (ну если и не все - то хоть по максимуму) чем-то одним, и чем? Чтоб максимально просто (попробовал Miranda NG, замучился со Skype, стер), обязательно безопасно (с гарантией, что хотя бы пароли не уйдут налево) - и охватывало как можно больше из перечисленного. Всякие видео-разговоры не интересуют, практически не использую - просто текст, передача файлов желательна, но не обязательна. Еще хотелось бы быструю реакцию на бурно меняющийся мир - сменили где-то протокол, и это было бы оперативно отработано.

Под Windows.

Кто что посоветует?

Comment: У скайпа и вайбера точно нет внешнего API, соответственно и клиентских приложений не может быть сторонних.

Comment: @NickVolynkin Ну, какая-то эмуляция Скайпа в Miranda точно есть, по крайней мере отправить сообщение мне удалось, но принять так и не вышло.

Comment: [**Rambox**](https://rambox.pro/) использую для данных целей. Спасибо.

Comment: Pidgin с плагинами. Не слежу за проектом сейчас, но раньше было очень неплохо